# PIL: saving file in python

Tags: python-2.7, save, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
in_put = raw_input("provide the image path: ")
pic_im = image.open(in_put)
pic_im.rotate(45).show()
pic_im.save("outputfile.jpg")
```

I use the above code to open and rotate the user input image.

but every time i have to manually change the name of "outputfile.jpg" while saving the image.

Please guide to save the modified image: for example.

if my original file path is E:\Picture\Nature.jpg

then it should save the modified file in save location with name E:\Picture\Nature_modified.jpg

Comment: you could try string replacement on `in_put` to change _.jpg_ to __modified.jpg_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
output_filename = in_put[0:len(in_put)-4] + "_modified.jpg" 
pic_im.save(output_filename)
```

Comment: @i.py Glad to help! Please mark it as answer as well, click checkbox near the answer.